# on click function jquery remove one object after user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the function chooseCharacter below, how might I call the three objects also entitled "thumbnail" while excluding the thumbnail designated "this" within the function (and subsequently, append !this to my HTML row "playerEnemies)?

(Further details: HTML index file has bootstrap rows that include charactersAvailable, playerCharacter, & playerEnemies.  I am able to empty the charactersAvailable row, append the clicked selection to playerCharacter, but I can't figure out how to choose the unselected objects from charactersAvailable and push them or append them to playerEnemies row)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var char1 = {
    name: "Yoda",
    hp: 900,
    attackPower: 1,
    defendPower: 2,
}
console.log (char1);

var char2 = {
    name: "Jyn Erso",
    hp: 21,
    attackPower: 3,
    defendPower: 4,
}
console.log (char2);

var char3 = {
    name: "Lando Calrissian",
    hp: 31,
    attackPower: 5,
    defendPower: 6,
}
console.log(char3);

var char4 = {
    name: "Count Dooku",
    hp: 102,
    attackPower: 7,
    defendPower: 8,
}
console.log(char4);

var playerHP;

var playerAttackPower;

var defenderHP;

var charactersAvailable = [char1, char2, char3, char4];

var playerSelection;

function chooseCharacter () {

$(".thumbnail").on("click", function () {
        playerSelection = this;
        console.log(this);
        $(".charactersAvailable").empty();
        $("#playerCharacterTitle").text("Player Character");
        $(".playerCharacter").addClass("playerGameSelection");
        $(".playerCharacter").append(this);
        $("#playerEnemiesTitle").text("Enemies to Attack");

})

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all of the other .thumbnail objects in the click handler:

```
$('.thumbnail').not(this);
```

... and you should be able to move them with:

```
$('.thumbnail').not(this).appendTo('.enemies');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this was also one of my ideas, but it does not work.  It does not break the code, but it also does not append anything to that particular row. (Or anywhere else).  Any other ideas?

Comment: Got it on a public page somewhere so I can play with it?

Comment: Just pushed to github, so it might take a few moment to load: https://paulaperoutka.github.io/Week-4-Game/
Thanks Sorak!

Comment: Please accept my answer if it solved your problem. Happy holidays!